# update query takes long time in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

i have a function which update  rows of a table , the update is done selecting the lowest creating date and comparing the respective billing dates ,there after increasing the creating date to top most creating date, i am trying to update the originated date based on this selections.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OriginatedDate_update( total in Number )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  intialCount Number(10);
  temp Number(10);
  count1 Number(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(p2.created_date)) INTO temp FROM discrepancy_grid_info p2 where billing_date is not null;
  intialCount :=1;
  temp :=temp+1;
  WHILE intialCount < temp loop 
     update (SELECT * FROM discrepancy_grid_info p1 WHERE (intialCount-1) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(p2.created_date)) FROM discrepancy_grid_info p2 WHERE p2.created_date < p1.created_date ) and billing_date is not null) f 
     set f.ORIGINATED_DATE=(SELECT MAX(p.ORIGINATED_DATE) FROM DISCREPANCY_GRID_INFO p where  p.PRIM_ID=f.PRIM_ID AND p.PLAN_NAME=f.PLAN_NAME and   p.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID IN (select process_instance_id from audit_process where client_vendor_id in (select id from client_vendor where vendor_id=(select vendor_id from client_vendor where id=(select client_vendor_id from audit_process where process_instance_id=f.process_instance_id)) and client_id=( select client_id  from client_vendor where id=(select client_vendor_id from audit_process where process_instance_id=f.process_instance_id)))) 
            and p.billing_date between add_months(trunc(f.billing_date,'mm'),-1) and last_day(add_months(trunc(f.billing_date,'mm'),-1)) and p.billing_date is not null and p.created_date < f.created_date  group by p.PRIM_ID,p.PLAN_NAME) 
    where f.billing_date is not null;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    count1 :=count1+SQL%ROWCOUNT;    
    intialCount :=intialCount+1;
    end loop;
  RETURN count1;
END;
```

Comment: You should only tag the DBMS relevant to what you are working with. You will also need to provide more details here. In fact, as posted you haven't actually asked a question at all.

Comment: show your code  ..

Comment: code is below, i am new to stack overflow i post in answer by mistake

Comment: @mktl Please update your question to include some sample data for your tables and the expected output after the update is complete. I'm pretty certain that your function is massively over-complicated and that it can be done in a single update (or merge) statement, but as things stand there's not enough information to even guess at what that update is trying to do (at least, not without an awful lot of work and guesswork on our part, which I, for one, don't have time to do).

Comment: how can i update the sample date here, data is not formatted once i try to update edit and update

Comment: main thing is query should be updated in an order starting with min created date to top

Comment: You can use the {} button (or simply add four spaces to the beginning of each line of the data) to retain the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Run just **ONE** query:

```
 update 
   discrepancy_grid_info p1 
  -- WHERE (intialCount-1) = 
  --  (
  -- SELECT * FROM discrepancy_grid_info p1 
  --     WHERE (intialCount-1) = (
  --         SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(p2.created_date)) 
  --         FROM discrepancy_grid_info p2 
  --         WHERE p2.created_date < p1.created_date 
  --   ) and */

 set ORIGINATED_DATE=(
   .... rest of your query goes here
)
WHERE p1.billing_date is not null ;
```

instead of repeating the same query tens, hundreds or maybe thousands number of times in a loop.
Remove the loop also, it is unneeded.
The query can be futhrer optimized, but this very simple change should give a huuuuuuuuge improvement.

Comment: i need the query to run on created_date increasing order, need to set originate_date = created_date if the calculate originated date is null.. can i achieve this in single loop

Comment: Could you explain why do you need to "update in certin order" ? By definition in SQL a table is a  set of unordered records, in particular in Oracle where by default a table is created as a heap organized table. tuples in the table have no any order, updating the table in any order doesn't make any sense to me. Run the single query agains your data, and then run your query 1000 times in an order, then compare results of both updates - is there any difference ?

Comment: discrepancy_grid_info  i have to consider three columns created_date, originated_date and billing_date.  based on the billing_date  i have to calculate the originated_date  if the calculated value is null then originated date = created date. this is implemented now for the records which are newly inserted  with the trigger . now i want  to update the old records in the same way.

Comment: if in 10 may 2014 a record is created  it should be updated first with created date , next in 11 june 2014 if a record is created and billing_date condition matches then  10 may 2014 will be originated date for the second record. billing_date  condtion : if  1 record has billing  july 2014 and second record hand aug 2014, third has sep 2014 then the condtion satisfies for all records, if the second recod is  aug 2014 and third record is nov 2014 then conditon only statisfies for second recod